# matching old column names and replacing with new from another dataframe (+ interactions)

Tags: r

I have a data frame (`df.subset`) that is a mix of original variables and some interactions with each other (cfr. `labs`). I want to rename the columns using an external data frame (`df_names`) by matching **old** names and replacing them with **new** (warning: interactions must be renamed too!).

```
set.seed(12345)

x1<- rnorm(100, 1000, 10)
x2<- rnorm(100, 200,1)
x3<- rnorm(100, 10000,400)
x4<- rnorm(100, 2405,28)

# starting dataframe
df<-data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4))

# i'm interested only in the variables and interactions contained in labs
labs<-c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x1*x2", "x1*x4", "x2*x3")
str(labs)

# all variables + all interactions
res <- cbind(df, do.call(cbind,combn(colnames(df), 2, 
                                        FUN= function(x) list(df[x[1]]*df[x[2]]))))

colnames(res)[-(seq_len(ncol(df)))] <-  combn(colnames(df), 2, 
                                               FUN = paste, collapse="*")

res

# final dataset
df.subset <- res[, labs]
df.subset

# use this df for new column names
df_names <- data.frame(old = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")
                       , new = c("tv", "radio", "outdoor", "cinema","something_else"))

df_names
```

I tried with `mapvalues` but no success

```
plyr::mapvalues(names(df.subset), from = df_names$old, to = df_names$new)
```

The output should be as below:

```
> colnames(df.subset)
[1] "tv"    "radio"    "outdoor"    "cinema"    "tv*radio" "tv*cinema" "radio*outdoor"
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple loop is this easiest way to do it:

```r
names(df.subset)
#> [1] "x1"    "x2"    "x3"    "x4"    "x1*x2" "x1*x4" "x2*x3"

for(i in seq(nrow(df_names))){
  names(df.subset) <- gsub(df_names$old[i], df_names$new[i], names(df.subset))
}

names(df.subset)
#> [1] "tv"            "radio"         "outdoor"       "cinema"       
#> [5] "tv*radio"      "tv*cinema"     "radio*outdoor"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for your reply! This answers the question, but can I kindly ask you to explain what does the loop do? at any iteration (from 1 to nrow(df_names)) I get the same results - so I am a bit confused here. Apologies for the very dumb question.

Comment: @JoeUK `seq(nrow(df_names))` is just a safer way of doing `1:nrow(df_names)`. The contents of the loop just iterate through each row of `df_names` and replaces any instances of `old` in the names of `df.subset` with the matching value of `new`.